# Error when trying to pull data from HTML with PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, php-7.2

I have a aws ec2 instance and I am running my html file and my php file on it. My web app is a submit form where people put in their name and email, and then hit enter to submit. When I try to run it I get this error on my browser:
(my aws endpoint)is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

When I change my php code just to echo back some text it works. So I think there is a syntax error with way I'm trying to get the string from my html.

```
<form method="get" action="contactform.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Your E-mail">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">
        SUBMIT
    </button>
</form>
```

```
//contactform.php

<?php
echo "Running..."

$name = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'name');
$mail = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'mail');

echo $name;
echo $mail;

?>
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error

```
<?php
echo "Running..."
```

Should be

```
<?php
echo "Running...";
```

with an `;`.

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected '$name' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Hey thank you so much, I clearly need to watch more PHP tutorials.

Comment: Sure, you can also use an IDE like Eclipse PDT, which will highlight simple syntax errors like this and do auto-coplete etc.   I been using Eclipse for years it's not the best IDE but it's free.